# How to print stack trace from logback custom layout?

Tags: stack-trace, logback

I'm writing a CustomLayout for logback, because I want to tweak thread names and logger names.  The logback documentation says

> In the above example, the doLayout method ignores any eventual exceptions contained in the event. In a real world layout implementation, you would most probably want to print the contents of exceptions as well.

Umm, yes, of course I want to print stack traces when the default implementation would.  But I can't find any instructions for doing so.  I downloaded the sources and looked around.  The following seems to work:

```
/**
 * How much stack to print if there's an exception.
 */
private List<String> stackOptionList = Arrays.asList("full");

@Override
public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
  StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer(128);
  . . .
  IThrowableProxy proxy = event.getThrowableProxy();
  if (proxy != null) {      
    ThrowableProxyConverter converter = new ThrowableProxyConverter();
    converter.setOptionList(stackOptionList);
    converter.start();
    sbuf.append(converter.convert(event));
    sbuf.append(CoreConstants.LINE_SEPARATOR);
  }
  . . .
  return sbuf.toString();
}
```

Is there a better/more approved way?

Comment: It took me forever to look for this answer and validate what I was doing. I started with the exact same approach as you did but as @Ceki mentioned I switched to the custom converters approach as its a lot easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ThrowableProxyConverter is the way to go to print the stack trace. Thus, the code you intend to use looks good. However, instead of writing a CustomLayout, you could adapt PatternLayout with [custom converters](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#customConversionSpecifier). In the vast majority of cases, that is the easier/better option.

Comment: @ceki Should one create, start, and stop a new `ThrowableProxyConverter` for every doLayout?

Answer (score 8):

This might help you:

[ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxyUtil](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ThrowableProxyUtil.html)

```
StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
....
IThrowableProxy throwbleProxy =  event.getThrowableProxy();
if (throwbleProxy != null) {
    String throwableStr = ThrowableProxyUtil.asString(throwbleProxy);
    sbuf.append(throwableStr);
    sbuf.append(CoreConstants.LINE_SEPARATOR);
}
```